# How to check multiple form submission with PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I have my own MVC applicaiton where I have 3 main area: model, view, controller.

In the view, I've created a form, to insert some data to the DB. The action is set to the same page and the type is: POST.

In the model, I have some basic checking if the form has been submitted or not. There is an 1 second sleep after that.

In the controller, I'm connecting the view and the model in a very simple way, so they can commuicate between each other.

However a problem is arising, whenever the visitor clicks multiple times on the submit button. Because there is 1 second waiting (it is intentional - so it looke like the system is processing the data), they can click multiple times to the button.

There is an issue with that, because this way, the data gets inserted to the database based on the amount of clicks. If I output a simple word, like "Foo" it will get displayed only 1 time (I guess this is because the page is reloading every time), however the data gets inserted multiple times to the DB.

Is there any way around this issue? My intention was to create a session and check if this is the first submit, else do nothing with the DB. However this didn't work, because the session always got the basic value upon the page load.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: What if you check if the record is inserted before you insert? Or even better - create a unique constraint to prevent duplicates?

Comment: I have tried to run a query which check fr uniqueness, but it seems like worthless. It seems like the page inserts everything before checking even if it exists. However I placed that in a condition to insert, ONLY if there is no record of that. I guess, somehow it checks 1 time if it exsits and then inserts multiple times - somehow the inserts stacks up.

Comment: Simplest way would be to handle it on the frontend with some simple javascript.

Comment: @Eugene The problem is, that if the user submits the page, they might provide empty fields, not valid fields, etc so I cannot just simply disable the button when they send the submit request, because they cannot resubmit their information only if they reload the page completely.

Comment: "It seems like the page inserts everything before checking even if it exists" --- a script does whatever you programmed. If it inserts before check, then it's you who did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Put some javascript on the front-end to disable the button upon being clicked and then submit the form - this is probably the easiest way but you may want to try and leave the front-end as uncluttered as possible.
2. Set a session variable before you load the page, then when you do the insert delete this session variable immediately after.  Before doing the insert you should check for the session variable - if it is set then the insert is allowed, if it is not then it isn't.  You may also want to add in code into a master controller (if all your controllers are derived from one master controller) that checks what controller has been called and then if the session variable that is set should be for a different controller then it should be deleted (so it no longer exists if the user goes to a different page without submitting the form).